# python entry widget and get method

Tags: python, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

Is there any way to put the textvariable in another variable and not have to use the ".get()"? I've been doing a lot of sifting thorugh tutorials and articles for what I realize is a very small issue but I'm probably misunderstanding something pretty key so i'm hoping someone can help me develop some intuition for the entry widget and .get() method.

Below is part of a script that I've been working on where I want to take the text entered in the entry box and use it later. I can use it if I use `search_word.get()`, but I don't why I can't do something like  `New_variable=search_word.get()` so that from that point on I can just use "New_variable".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Text_input_window = Tk()
Text_input_window.geometry('600x350+100+200')
Text_input_window.title("Test")

label_1=ttk.Label(Text_input_window, text="Enter word to search:", background="black", foreground="white")
label_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

search_word=StringVar()
entry_1=ttk.Entry(Text_input_window,textvariable=search_word, width=40, background="white")
entry_1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
New_variable=StringVar()
New_variable=search_word.get()
def click():
    print(New_variable)
    print(search_word.get())
    Text_input_window.destroy()

btn_1=ttk.Button(Text_input_window, text="submit", width=10, command=click)
btn_1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)


Text_input_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: problem is not `.get()` but how all GUIs works. `mainloop()` starts program so `New_variable=search_word.get()` is executed before you even see window - so it tries to get text before you put text in `Entry`. You have to do it inside `click()` which is executed after you put text in entry and click button.

Comment: BTW: if you have `New_variable = StringVar()` then you should to use `.set()` - `New_variable.set(search_word.get())` - but it still have to be in `click()`. Using `=` you put normal string in place of `StringVar()`

Comment: Thank you for the explaination... ahh ok '.set()' … but when I do:'def click(): New_variable.set(search_word.get()) print(str(New_variable)) Text_input_window.destroy()' I get PY_VAR1 … is that the best I can get or is there a way to get the string I typed in the entry box?

Comment: you have to use `.get()` to get text from `StringVar` - `print(New_variable.get())`

Comment: if you don't want to use `StringVar` then don't use it - assign text to normal variable `variable = search_word.get()` and then use it as normal string - `print(variable)` . You don't need even `search_word` because you can get text directly from entry - `variable = entry.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not `.get()` but how all GUIs works.

`mainloop()` starts program so `new_variable = search_word.get()` is executed before you even see window - so it tries to get text before you put text in `Entry`.

You have to do it inside `click()` which is executed after you put text in entry and click button.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def click():
    global new_variable # inform function to use external/global variable instead of creating local one

    #new_variable = entry.get()  # you can get it directly from `Entry` without StringVar()
    new_variable = search_word.get()

    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

new_variable = '' # create global variable with default value

root = tk.Tk()

search_word = tk.StringVar()

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=search_word)
entry.pack()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="submit", command=click)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop() # start program

# --- after closing window ---

print('new_variable:', new_variable)
print('search_word:', search_word.get())  # it seems it still exists
# print('entry:', entry.get())  # `Entry` doesn't exists after closing window so it gives error
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to put the textvariable in another variable and not have to use the ".get()"?

No, there is not. Tkinter variables are objects, not values. Anytime you want to use a value from a tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc) you must call the `get` method.